# power rating difference of UPS - safe to use?

Tags: power-supply

My UPS has the following power rating for the outlets where I'm supposed to be connecting my devices for uninterrupted supply:

```
230VAC/50HZ
```

There are 2 outlets in total.

but, my monitor has the following power specification:

```
100-240V ~ 50/60Hz 0.8A
```

I don't know much on hardwares and I'm worried if it's safe to connect my monitor on the supply.

Comment: You need to edit your question. Your supply on shows voltage (you can ignore Hertz which is frequency as it will be fine). So power rating for your supply. And you suggest 2 devices but only show 1 device. Your supply should be about double the power rating of all your devices together to allow for startup surge current.

Comment: @John, thanks for replying. I didn't understand the latter half of your comment, but, what I mean is that there are 2 outlets given by the UPS with the same power rating. I didn't mean two devices were connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine.

Different countries use different voltage (V) and frequency (Hz). The most common ones are 120V 60Hz (America) and 230V 50Hz (most other places). Your monitor works on all of them.

Your UPS outputs 230V 50Hz. Presumably that's the same sort of power that comes out of the wall in your country. Your monitor is okay with this kind of power.

If you moved to the USA, you'd have 120V 60Hz power. Your monitor would be okay with that kind of power too, but your UPS wouldn't. You'd need to buy an American UPS.

Comment: what does the VAC mean and why is the latter given in range(100-240V)?

Comment: @bzal VAC means V AC (volts, alternating current) and it's 100-240V because the monitor is okay with anything in between 100 and 240V, for example 160V is also good. There are no countries that use 160V. But if there were, it'd be okay for the monitor.

Comment: can these power ratings allow me to predict how long the UPS would last? there's no utility for the UPS.

Comment: @bzal In principle, the number 0.8A can be used to calculate it, BUT I don't think 0.8A is correct. If your monitor actually used 0.8A, it would mean it used tons of power (for a monitor). I think 0.8A is like a maximum number, they're promising the monitor won't use more than 0.8A, but they don't say how much it will *actually* use.

Comment: @bzal You could just unplug the UPS from the wall and use a stopwatch to measure how long before it turns off

Comment: one thing I forgot to ask was: will increasing the brightness of the monitor consume more power from the UPS?

Comment: @bzal Yes but monitors don't use very much power anyway.